# I am getting sum of last index but initial index give me 0 why?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("SUM OF TWO ARRY");
for (int l = 0; l <= result.length-1; l++) {
     System.out.println(result[l]);
}
```

This loop gives me the sum of the last index but not of the initial index and this is what I am doing before this code!

```
for (int m = 0; m <= rank.length-1; m++) {
     result[r]=(rank[m])+(rank1[m]);
}
```

Comment: what is `r` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping using `m`, so for `result[]` too, you'd use `m` instead of `r`.

Change:

```
result[r]=(rank[m])+(rank1[m]);
```

to

```
result[m]=(rank[m])+(rank1[m]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answers guys i have replace the variable and its done :)